# Disable History, Properties and Subscription tabs

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I am trying to disable history and properties tabs from my report manager for some users.

I've been looking for advice on the internet but did not find anything about this.

Has anyone any idea on what configuration elements I have to modify so as to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom role:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms159840%28SQL.90%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I've already seen this link but did not manage to do what I want.
Let's say I've got on Windows group named "RSUsers" with a Windows user called "RSUser". 
Could please explain me how I should proceed so that users in the RSUsers group can only execute reports (not seeing propeties, history or subscriptions) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You create a custom role with the permissions you require - this is an RS role and nothing to do with Active Directory groups. Then you just give this role to YOURDOMAIN\RSUSERS on whatever you are permissioning (report or folder)